# UITableView scrolling resets UIImageViews

Tags: uitableview, uiimageview

I have some UIImageViews animated via facebook pop on a UIView. A UiTableView on top of the UIView holds the tweets. Somehow my ImageViews get reposition on scrolling. I'm not sure if it's facebook pop API related or there is a problem on how i setup the tableview ?

the UITableView with the tweets are done programmatically in the viewDidLoad of my controller

```
self.fireTweet = [[CustomUITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(/*160.0f*/self.MainView.frame.size.width, 200.0f, 320.0f, 340.0f)];
 [self.fireTweet registerClass:[TWTRTweetTableViewCell class]  forCellReuseIdentifier:TweetTableReuseIdentifierFire];
self.fireTweet.delegate = self;
self.fireTweet.dataSource = self;
self.fireTweet.layer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
self.fireTweet.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
self.fireTweet.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
self.fireTweet.estimatedRowHeight = 340;
...
```

And some facebook pop related animation code here

```
POPSpringAnimation *anim = [POPSpringAnimation animationWithPropertyNamed:kPOPLayerPosition];
anim.springBounciness = 10.0;
anim.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake((view.frame.size.width / 2.0) + x, (view.frame.size.height/2.0) + y) ];

//shrink
POPSpringAnimation *imgAnimShrink = [POPSpringAnimation animationWithPropertyNamed:kPOPLayerSize];
imgAnimShrink.property = [POPAnimatableProperty propertyWithName:kPOPLayerSize];
imgAnimShrink.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(50, 50)];



[view pop_addAnimation:anim forKey:@"bottom"];

[view pop_addAnimation:imgAnimShrink forKey:@"imageShrink"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out myself. Just turn off the autolayout and it got fixed